# How to create two dependency folders after webpack bundling in Vue CLI?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, config, bundle, vue-cli

My English skills are not very good, so I apologize for using GPT for translation!

I have a requirement that needs to be addressed, as follows:
Bundle a project into two folders, one named "base," and the other named "extra."
Base folder: can run independently and, if necessary, incorporate the contents of the "extra" folder, as an example, similar to the standard version of a project.
Extra folder: does not need to run independently and requires dependence on the "base" to function, similar to additional DLC in a game.

The structure is as follows.

```
base
├── index.html
├── *.js
├── *.css
│
extra
├── *.js
├── *.css
```

I would like to ask if webpack can fulfill my requirements. If there is any code or similar issues, please let me know. Thank you for your assistance!

### vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/cli-test/' : '/',
  publicPath: '/',
  pages: {
    main: {
      entry: 'src/main.ts', // 主入口
      template: 'public/index.html',
    },
    extra: {
      entry: 'src/extra.ts', // 額外入口
      template: 'public/index.html',
    }
  }
}
```